# Create a Spark Data Frame with only one column having number from 1 to 1 million

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How can I create a Spark Data Frame with only one column having numbers from 1 to 10 million?

I have tried using Python to create a list of numbers ranging from 1 to 10 million but my solution is failing.
Please advise, thank you in advance.

I am using below query:

```
df_base1 = sqlc.range(0, 1000000)
```

But it's failing:

> An error was encountered:
>   Invalid status code '500' from http://:8999/sessions/401/statements with error payload: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: RPC channel is closed."

Comment: Please provide a code example of your current solution buddy.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. It is the right way to do it. The exception is probably a result of something else. Could you post full traceback, please?

Answer (score 0):

`df_base1 = sqlc.range(0, 1000000)`

Works fine.
There was some environment issue.